# Why C# compiler doesn't call implicit operator. Compiler bug?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates, implicit-conversion

Consider the following struct:

```
struct SomeWrapper
{
    public Guid guid;

    public static implicit operator SomeWrapper(Guid guid) => new SomeWrapper {guid = guid};
}
```

This structure defines an implicit operator for treating `Guid` as `SomeWrapper`, very straightforward.
All of the following methods compile, except the first one `PleaseDoNotCompile`:

```
static Task<SomeWrapper> PleaseDoNotCompile() => Task.Run(() => Guid.NewGuid());

static Task<SomeWrapper> WhyDoYouCompile() => Task.Run(() =>
{
    return Guid.NewGuid();

    return new SomeWrapper();
});

static SomeWrapper IUnderstandWhyYouCompile() => Guid.NewGuid();

static async Task<SomeWrapper> IUnderstandWhyYouCompileToo() => await Task.Run(() => Guid.NewGuid());
```

In particular, `WhyDoYouCompile` is just the first method with an additional return statement returning a `SomeWrapper` value. It is obvious that return is unreachable code. And still it compiles while the first one does not.

So, there is actually another difference, besides the additional return statement, between these two methods: `PleaseDoNotCompile` uses `Task.Run<Guid>(Func<Guid> function)` whereas `WhyDoYouCompile` uses `Task.Run<SomeWrapper>(Func<SomeWrapper> function)`. So, that additional return actually changes the overlaod that is used.

Nevertheless, `IUnderstandWhyYouCompileToo`, which is just the `PleaseDoNotCompile` with the async and await keywords uses also `Task.Run<Guid>(Func<Guid> function)` and it does compile.

So, the question is simply why `PleaseDoNotCompile` does not compile while the other methods do? What am I missing?

Comment: Because `Task<Guid>` cannot be converted to `Task<SomeWrapper>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is explained in the [Inferred Return Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#inferred-return-type) section of the language spec.

During type inference, the compiler has to figure out what the return type for the lambdas you pass to `Task.Run` are, in order to infer the generic parameter for `Task.Run`. The rules are (for a lambda `F`):

> - If the body of `F` is an expression that has a type, then the inferred result type of `F` is the type of that expression.
> - If the body of `F` is a block and the set of expressions in the block's return statements has a best common type `T`, then the inferred result type
>   of `F` is `T`.
> - Otherwise, a result type cannot be inferred for `F`.

For `PleaseDoNotCompile`, point 1 applies, and the return type is inferred to be `Guid`, so a `Task<Guid>` is returned by `Task.Run`. Note that the fact that you are assigning to a `Task<SomeWrapper>` is not taken into account, as usual in type inference. For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string t = F(); // cannot infer type!
}

public static T F<T>()
{
    return default(T);
}
```

In `WhyDoYouCompile`, the second point applies, and the compiler finds a "best common type" between the type of `Guid.NewGuid()` and `new SomeWrapper()`. Even though the second return is not reachable, the compiler still considers it in this process. It sounds silly I know, but that's the spec!

The rules for finding a best common type are specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#finding-the-best-common-type-of-a-set-of-expressions). It involves quite a bit of the type inference algorithm, so I won't explain it in detail here. I hope that you'll agree that *intuitively*, the best common type between `Guid` and `SomeWrapper` is `SomeWrapper`, since `Guid` can be converted to `SomeWrapper`.

Therefore, the generic parameter for `Task.Run` gets inferred as `SomeWrapper`, and you get a `Task<SomeWrapper>` as expected.

To get the expression-bodied lambda to work, you can simply specify the type parameters for `Task.Run`:

```
Task.Run<SomeWrapper>(() => Guid.NewGuid())
```